# Double Constrained Loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have an issue which is rather simple in theory. I just can't seem to wrap my head around a solution. I have 2 Pandas dataframes.

Dataframe A:

```
Date           Currency    
-------------------------
2019-11-29     EUR
2019-11-29     USD
.              GBP
.              .
.              .
2019-10-31
```

Dataframe B:

```
Date          Currency   Conversion
-----------------------------------
2019-11-29    USD        0.79
2019-11-29    GBP        1.23
2019-11-29    CHF        1.41
2019-11-28    USD        .
.
.
.
2019-10-31   USD         .
2019-10-31   GBP
2019-10-31   USD
```

I essentially have a long list of trades in Dataframe A, around 5-15 a day. The instruments are bought in different currencies, which all should be denominated in euros. I wrote a piece from SQL that retrieves the conversion rates (from currency XX to EUR) at all dates in the period.

Now I need to add a column to dataframe A:

```
IF DataframeA[Date] = DataframeB[Date] AND DataframeA[Currency] = DataframeB[Currency]
```

then the corresponding conversion rate should be added.

The IF statement in itself I can do, but I can't seem to iterate and update as my script runs. Any ideas?

Best
Patrick

Comment: what column do you want to add if the condition is true? Or do you want to add the condition column itself. Do you want the relevant conversion rate?

Comment: Yes, the conversion rate! 
So, in Case of the first row, I would like to add a column to dataframe A, "Conversion value", with the value 0.79.

Answer (score 2):

DataframeA = pd.merge(DataframeA, DataFrameB, on=['Date', 'Currency'])

by default it's inner join. you can choose to modify that accordingly by using the option Ex: how = 'outer' in the merge command.
Further, drop or keep the column as you like or choose to add suffix or prefix in the common columns coming from two dataframes. Read the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)